# Working wihtout a table when I use Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a Rails application, where I need to show a form, and process the submitted form. This form has a couple of fields in it, and based on the input of the fields, it's supposed to re-direct the user to one of the existing views, when submitted.

Let's call the form: select_area

I create scaffolding as follows:

```
rails g login email_address:string password:string --skip-stylesheets
```

When I try to create the Bootstrap views:

```
rails g bootstrap:themed logins -f
```

I get the following error:
    `query': Mysql2::Error: Table 'x2live.logins' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM`logins` (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

I also get errors when I do:

```
rails g boostrap:themed logins
```

How do I suppress ActiveRecord in the Login model? I am also using the mysql2 gem

Comment: Someone edited my question, and changed the subject from "Rails: Working without a table when I used Bootstrap", to "Working without a table when I used Bootstrap". When I asked questions, I purposely include the environment in the subject, as this helps people narrow down their search when doing a global search. Is it against the rules to include the environment in the subject line?

Comment: Does `rails g NAME` default to `rails g scaffold`? Was the intent of this generator to create a scaffold?

Comment: You should probably read some docs on how the rails generator works, as this does not related to my question at all.

Comment: You have a typo in your command, which made it confusing to those of us trying to answer your question. Sorry

Comment: I think you mean `rails g scaffold login email_address:string password:string --skip-stylesheets`?

Comment: yes, scaffold is missing, but the issue is the dependence on the table being there. One workaround is to actually create the table, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the migrations?

`bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: No, as there is no migration file for the logins table. I specifically ran the rails generator with the option NOT to generate a migration file, hence my question: is it possible to do what I'm trying to do, without creating a table?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't know the generator function that well.  Where did you define it not to create a table?